# install XCA 2 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I'm using a great piece of SW for managing SSL certificates: XCA (X Certificate and Key management http://xca.hohnstaedt.de).

Initially I used the version already packaged in Ubuntu, namely 1.4, but it proved to be quite old when colleagues using Windows opened my certificates database file. We discovered at that moment that last version is 2.1.2, and it's the current version for Windows users. And it uses a different database.

So I need to update XCA on my Xubuntu 18.04 LTS machine but...I cannot find any package...is there any? Should I compile it from scratch? (it's a nightmare I had ages ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to find any package up to date and ready to be installed onto my linux box.
So I went the building route.

The following are the steps that made it work (each one was needed, otherwise it wouldn't work). Maybe there's  a better path anyway, I'm not a building expert at all!

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake git wget curl
sudo apt-get install cmake gcc g++ qt4-qmake
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
sudo apt-get install openssl libnss3 libnss3-dev
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install checkinstall

cd xca-2.1.2/

./bootstrap 
mkdir Build
cd Build/
../configure && make -j10

sudo checkinstall
```

checkinstall needed a description of the SW and a version number (2.1.2).

HTH

Comment: Sadly, I just tried to build xca on Ubuntu 18.04.3, and the above instructions weren't enough.  qt-sdk no longer exists as a package, the virtual package that seemed to have replaced it didn't.  I had to install autoconf and pkg-config, libtool, and those pulled in another big pile, yet it still won't build.  It can't find openssl headers, I think, and and this point I'm giving up.  I'll just have to use XCA on windows instead.

Comment: I get the following error "Error: dependency is not satisfiable: libqt5core5a(>= 5.12.2)Type a message" while trying the installation of .deb file using gdebi installer. Is there a way to verify the current version?

Answer (score 1):

For xca 2.2.1 on debian 9.12, this worked from an almost clean install (these, and their dependencies, may be optional `git xscreensaver cinnamon-core task-cinnamon-desktop desktop-base google-chrome-stable less bzip2 zip unzip`):

```sh
git clone https://github.com/chris2511/xca.git
cd xca
git checkout RELEASE.2.2.1
sudo apt install cmake autotools-dev automake qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools openssl libssl-dev libnss3-dev pkg-config libtool
./bootstrap && mkdir Build && cd Build && ../configure; make -j6
sudo make install
# git reset --hard && git clean -xf # needed to retry build
/usr/local/bin/xca
```